# Flow to retrieve ItemID for sharepoint files uploaded to onedrive by copying them to a locally synced folder

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, onedrive

My C# application should be able to upload/update Sharepoint online files. Currently i'm using Microsoft Graph to upload them directly to the web. However large files and a slow internet connection makes many uploads fail because users have to shutdown the application before the upload process is done.

I was thinking about syncing the Sharepoint document library locally using OneDrive for business. Then instead of uploading the file directly to the web, copy it to the local directory instead, and have the OneDrive client take care of the upload process.

However, my application should keep track of the files so I need the Sharepoint ItemId for the files being uploaded. My current idea is to simply keep track of which files were copied, and then keep polling Sharepoint using Microsoft Graph to get the itemId using the filename/path until it returns a hit? Is there a better option? And is there a way to see if the upload process is complete or still running?

Comment: Are you using WebClient or WebSocket?  WebSocket may solve issue : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscriptions-socketio?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http